# Does code allow connecting underground my galvanized 3" riser to a schedule 40 3" PVC conduit for incoming service?

Tags: electrical-panel, conduit

I am upgrading my electrical service to 200A, so I have to run new 3" schedule 40 PVC conduit underground (encased in concrete) between my main panel, and the city's electrical pull box per city's requirements. It calls for a schedule 80 riser into my main electrical panel. I would like to use my existing 3" galvanized metal riser I have now because schedule 80 is hard to obtain and expensive. I have not found any answers online on how to correctly connect them together underground, and I have asked the city 2 mos. ago about it, but they haven't gotten back to me yet (still waiting).

What is the correct way to do this and pass inspection? If it's not allowed, can I glue schedule 80 and 40 together even though there's a difference in thickness between them. Don't want to assume here, so there are no surprises!

AL

Comment: Here's one company's explanation of how to do a schedule 40 burial in concrete: https://www.cantexinc.com/products/pvc-pipe-conduit/pvc-pipe-installation/pvc-pipe-cement-installation

Comment: From the net: "The major difference between schedule 40 and schedule 80 pipe is the wall thickness, inside diameter, and their weight. Schedule 80 will have a greater wall thickness, a smaller inside diameter and a higher weight than Schedule 40 pipe at a given nominal pipe size."

Comment: A conduit website suggests "Schedule 40 and 80 can be connected with the use of couplings or their integral bell. The inside diameter of the spigot of the Schedule 80 conduit should be reamed to allow a smooth transition from the 40 to the 80." Their FAQ is at http://www.primeconduit.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Sch4080_FAQ.pdf

Comment: Big box doesn't sell schedule 80. You need to go to real electrical supply for that, but they should have loads of it.

Comment: No, Schedule 80 is sold out and very expensive where I live. ~$145 each for 10 ft straight segments and 90-degree sweeps. It's ridiculous.  I need 35 ft + 3 sweeps = ~$1000.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple kinds of galvanized steel conduit. I'll assume your riser is the "rigid metal conduit" (RMC) variety. Rigid is usually produced with male threaded ends; you can use a PVC female threaded adapter to make the connection. I find it's easier to put the adapter onto the metal pipe first, then solvent weld the PVC pipe into the adapter second. (photo: Cantex/homedepot.com)

[image: female threaded adapter]

If the RMC isn't threaded at the end you could use a compression connector to provide the male thread on the metal side of things and the PVC female threaded adapter above to complete the connection. Note that metal conduits have different outside diameters; you'll need to confirm whether yours is RMC, IMC, or EMT and get the correct connector. You can measure the circumference of the tube with a string or strip of paper to identify which kind it is. (photo: Halex/homedepot.com)

[image: compression connector]

Finally, if you opt to replace the metal riser with SCH80 PVC, no worries: with PVC pipe it is the *outside dimension* which is controlled, precisely so that SCH40 and SCH80 (and other) wall thicknesses can all use the same size fittings. You just get a 3" coupling and glue the SCH40 into one side and the SCH80 into the other side.

If your prior service was direct-bury cable it may be that the existing riser has no elbow below ground. In that case you'll need to get one. A "long sweep" or "long radius" elbow will be much easier to pull cable through. The 24" radius might be a good choice since you may be burying about 24" deep anyway. These are not often found in a home center, though. You may have to go to an electrical distributor to get it, but if you'll be the person pulling the wires, you'll be glad to have it!

Comment: My current 125A service entrance wire is direct burial, and the riser pipe is threaded to the main panel using a metal collar, but I don't believe the bottom of the metal galvanized pipe that's inserted into the ground (dirt) is threaded. Let just assume it's not, since I can't access it until I am ready to cut power to the house and do the install -- it will be in a couple of months.

Comment: If the riser is movable(can be placed in a car), and can be threaded, can take to your local rental tool place and put the threads on there.  Will save one trip anyway.

Comment: I only have to install new 3" schedule 40 PVC conduit encased in concrete with 90-degree bends because direct burial is no longer allowed. I was told a maximum of 3 bends (sweeps @ 36") between the panel and pull box. My city will then provide and install (pull) the new 200A service entrance cable through the PVC conduit. Not every city does that for you free of charge!

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the stuff that's in the dirt will be **rusted**. So I would not count on being able to reuse it. However if you want to use RMC for a stub-up, sure. Or use RMC for the whole shebang, only needs 6" of cover.

Comment: Don't assume. It's galvanized, and not rusted. It was removed from my old panel, and reused on my new upgraded 200A panel by my electrician. It's been awhile since the upgrade due to covid,so I can't remember if it's threaded, and it's not accessible until I remove the concrete around it when I dig the trench.

Comment: And replace the service wire.